# Symbol ' in Vue.js does not work for my template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I started to learn Vue.js. I grabbed some sample code from an example but its template is inside an HTML file. I want to put into my app.js as a template, like they show in video tutorials I watched. But my editor is showing me an error when I do it and also my console gives off error. This is my code:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        ...
    },
    filters: {
        ...
    },
    methods: {
        ...
    },
    template: '
      <div>
      
        <h1 class="main">Sunrise Vitamins</h1>
        
        <ul class="vitamins">
          <li class="vitamin_type" v-for="vitamin in vitamins" v-on:click="toggleActive(vitamin)" v-bind:class="{ 'active' : vitamin.active }">
            
            <span>{{vitamin.name}}</span> <span>{{vitamins.price | currency}}</span>
          
            </li>
        </ul>
        
        <p class="total">
          <span>Total:</span> <span>{{total() | currency}}</span>
        </p>
    
      </div>
    '
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using the wrong symbol, it’s not ‘ as an apostrophe, it’s ` located in a top left corner of a keyboard next to 1 and esc if you’re on a Mac. Sorry not sure what’s it called. It’s not only for Vue, it’s ES6 feature. I recommend you check that and also the rest of the features that were introduced in ECMAScript 2015 here:

https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#template-strings

Comment: OMG! Woops! Thanks! I will do that.